# What does "research design" refer to in a peer review form?

Tags: peer-review, journals, computer-science

One of the questions posed to me as a peer reviewer is:

> Is the research design appropriate?

In my understanding, that would be an applicable question if the manuscript I am reviewing was presenting some kind of novel design or methodology.

In this case, I am reviewing a paper that is mainly doing analysis of extracted data. Is the question no longer applicable (that is an optional answer) since there is no new scheme presented, or could it still refer to the chosen methodology for the data extraction and analysis, even if it is still not a new approach?

Comment: Why do you think it's only applicable if it's novel? I don't understand why the question suggests that to you, and it would improve my answer to know.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I am just wondering whether the word "design" means there has to be some kind of design presented in the work. Perhaps it is also relevant that a question about whether the methods used are described follows this one.

Comment: Are you a native English speaker / are you translating this prompt for us?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I am bilingual so yes, in a sense. I am not translating, the form is in English. Perhaps it is also useful to point out that this is a computer science journal, hence my doubts about the meaning of design.

Comment: Ah, I'm not in CS, so I'm not sure why "design" would only apply to novel designs.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- There is a good chance I am overthinking this...besides, are the reviewer forms different accross journals if it is the same publisher?

Comment: Most probably, I don't want to lead you astray though. Probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally research design would refer to the methodology. Is is appropriate to answer the research questions? Is it sufficient? Is the suggested data collection and analysis (if any) valid? Is it likely we can trust the results that flow from the design?

The design could be entirely standard, but it still has to match the question and be appropriate to the population (assuming it is a data driven research).

Not all CS research fits the above, of course, so you need to extrapolate a bit. For example, if you are building a better compiler optimizer (I know, so last-century), then you need to specify in which dimensions it is better and how you will verify that it is.

Answer (score 3):

Research design is simply the methodology used to answer the research questions. Usually the methodology is NOT novel. The journal is asking you, "Did the researcher choose the right methods to answer the research questions?"